# autocmplete in asp.net with ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to autocomplete textbox, and i downloaded source code from any website,
Here is aspx page code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Ajax AutoCompleteExtender without Webservice</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<ajax:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"/>
<div>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCountry" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<ajax:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server"       
      TargetControlID="txtCountry" 
      MinimumPrefixLength="1" EnableCaching="true" CompletionSetCount="1"         
      CompletionInterval="1000" ServiceMethod="GetCountries" >
</ajax:AutoCompleteExtender> 
</div>
</form>
```

and here is codebehind file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static List<string> GetCountries(string prefixText)
  {
      SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ToString());
      con.Open();
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select varStateName from tblStateMaster where varStateName like @Name'%'", con);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", prefixText);
      SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
      da.Fill(dt);
      List<string> CountryNames = new List<string>();
      for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
      {
          CountryNames.Add(dt.Rows[i][1].ToString());
      }
      return CountryNames;
  }

}
```

It could not generate proper output and i am not able to debug this service, so how can i debug such service, and please tell me where is exact problem and which points should be remember for service and autocomplete, 
And one more thing can i do it with dropdownlist?

Comment: Check in console tab of browser to see whether any error is thrown so that post is success or failed we can know and proceed further.

Comment: http://localhost:4214/AutoCompleteWithoutWebservice/Default.aspx/GetCountries 500 (Internal Server Error) ScriptResource.axd?d=xFy-GoE0E7oWmmQPjdOewpUdg3T6QE1a-Dr1c7ntrrMYFn09YO0CJ0Y17MZmZkofkJ9UkKGOqjSXiY…:6954

Comment: Rad [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/78704/Different-Approaches-for-Implementing-the-JQuery) from CodeProject.You will never had a problem.

Comment: @ Farhad Jabiye,I use AjaxControlToolKit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the issue is in your query and more specifically in the `%`, try to include it in your parameter instead:

```
prefixText = string.Concat(prefixText, "%");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select varStateName from tblStateMaster where varStateName like @Name", con);
```

**EDIT**

Ok, so digging around, according to official [examples](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act_autocomplete_simple.ashx) from Microsoft, your method signature should look like this (notice the additional parameters):

```
public static string[] GetCountries(string prefixText)
{
   // your stuff
}
```

Comment: Okay i tried example and i removed contextKey then it works on example but with database there is an error with % sign

Comment: Hey how could i do it with dropdownlist or combobox?? please help